# nodejs - Detect end of file (EOF)

Tags: node.js, fs

I need to read a file into buffers in nodejs and use the "old" read() function for this, as I need to have strict size buffers.

I have a loop to read the file chunk by chunk. But how can I detect if the end of file (EOF) is reached?
My code is:

```
do
  fs.read(fd, buf1, 0, CHUNKSIZE, null, (err, bytesRead, buffer) => {
    console.log("Bytes read: " + bytesRead);
    console.log("Buffer: " + buffer);   
  });
while (!EOF)
```

But how can I determine EOF?

Comment: 0 bytes read usually means EOF. But you should use `readFile` if you are going to buffer the entire file anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The end of stream is when `chunkSize > bytesRead`, be sure to convert the buffer to a string using `bytesRead` or you may end up with junk characters.

```
function readAll(fd, chunkSize, callback) {
    fs.read(fd, new Buffer(chunkSize), 0, chunkSize, null, (err, bytesRead, buffer) => {
        if (err) {
            return callback(err);
        }

        console.log(buffer.toString('utf8', 0, bytesRead));
        if (chunkSize > bytesRead) {
            callback();
        } else {
            readAll(fd, chunkSize, callback);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks a lot.